# Question about vector-matrix derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, matrix-calculus

Let's say I have a matrix like below:

$$ W = \begin{bmatrix}
w_{1,1} & w_{1,2} \\
w_{2,1} & w_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$ \vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$ \vec{y} = W\vec{x} =
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{1,1}x_1 + w_{1,2}x_2 \\
w_{2,1}x_1 + w_{2,2}x_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

then, how do I calculate the $\partial {\vec{y}} \over \partial {W}$?

Comment: According to Wikipedia.org [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Other_matrix_derivatives], there is no consensus about the definition of a derivative of a vector by a matrix. Can you be more specific? Are you interested for instance in the 3-indexes tensor $\frac{\partial (\vec y)_i}{\partial W_{jk}}$?

Comment: I have a hunch that you are trying to use the Chain Rule to calculate something, and you **think** you need this derivative in order to do that. If this is case, you'd be better off performing the calculation _without_ using the chain rule.

Comment: @M.Marciani Yes, exactly. I read the [material](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/vecDerivs.pdf) about vector derivatives, but I didn't understand about dealing with more than two dimensions. Specifically, I can't imagine the result that 3-indices tensor $\partial{\vec{y}_i} \over \partial{W_jk}$.

Comment: @greg  yeah, now I'm studying about Back Propagation in Neural Network, that is why I wonder it.But, unfortunately,  I didn't understand your saying that "calculation _without using chain rule"_. Why is better?