# Question about vector-matirix derivative in back propagation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Let's say I have a matrix like below:

$$ W = \begin{bmatrix}
w_{1,1} & w_{1,2} \\
w_{2,1} & w_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$ \vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$ \vec{y} = W\vec{x} =
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{1,1}x_1 + w_{1,2}x_2 \\
w_{2,1}x_1 + w_{2,2}x_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In back-propagation, it is needed to calculate the $\partial {\vec{y}} \over \partial {W}$ to update  $W$.

But, according to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Other_matrix_derivatives), there is no consensus about the definition of a derivative of a vector by a matrix.

Then, how can I get the value of $\partial {\vec{y}} \over \partial {W}$?

Comment: As greg says on your [original post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3788504/81360), it's best to go through the calculation for the back propagation derivative without using this derivative directly. Perhaps if you include the full form of the (scalar-valued or vector-valued) function that you wanted to differentiate, somebody could show you how to proceed without getting mired in order $3$ tensors

Comment: Can you point where did you saw that is needed to calculate this derivative? Usually the back-propagation is interested in minimize the loss function, which is a norm (scalar value). The derivative is with respect to this norm function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever your notion of $\frac{\partial y}{\partial W}$, part of the data carried by this object is the set of all partial derivatives $\frac{\partial y}{\partial W_{ij}}$, and these derivatives should form all "entries" of $\frac{\partial y}{\partial W}$.  In this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation#Finding_the_derivative_of_the_error), the author(s) use only these partial derivatives and do not make any reference to a "total" derivative $\frac{\partial y}{\partial W}$.

Let $e_1,e_2$ denote the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^2$, i.e. the columns of the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix. We can see that these partial derivatives are given by
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial W_{ij}} = x_j e_i.
$$
To put things in terms of scalar entries, we would say that
$
\frac{\partial y_k}{\partial W_{ij}} = \delta_{ik} x_j,
$ where $y_k$ denotes the $k$th entry of $y$ and $\delta_{ik}$ denotes a "Kronecker delta".

Now, in terms of the [total/Frechet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition), we could say the following. $y(W)$ defines a function from $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$ to $\Bbb R^2$, so for any $W \in \Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$, $D_Wy(X) = Dy(X)$ defines a linear map from $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$ to $\Bbb R^2$; specifically, for any $H \in \Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$, we have
$$
Dy(X)(H) = y(H) = Hx.
$$
Although it is not an array of entries, this function $Dy$ is the operator that the array/tensor $\frac{\partial y}{\partial W}$ would represent.
We can recover the partial derivatives by evaluating the "directional derivatives" $d_Wy(X)(E_{ij})$, where $E_{ij} = e_ie_j^T$ is the matrix with a $1$ in the $i,j$ entry and zeros elsewhere.  Indeed, we have
$$
Dy(X)(E_{ij}) = E_{ij} x = e_i (e_j^Tx) = x_j e_i.
$$
The chain rule tells us the following: for any function $g:\mathcal Z \to \Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$, we may compute the total derivative of $y \circ g$ as follows. For any $z \in \mathcal Z$, the derivative (a linear map from $\mathcal Z$ to $\Bbb R^{2}$) is given by
$$
D(y \circ g)(z) = Dy(g(z)) \circ Dg(z),
$$
where $Dy(g(z))$ is a linear map from $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2} \to \Bbb R^2$ and $Dg(z)$ is a linear map from $\mathcal Z$ to $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$. More concretely, if $h \in \mathcal Z$, then the directional derivative "along" $h$ should be given by
$$
D(y \circ g)(z)(h) = [Dy(g(z)) \circ Dg(z)](h) = [Dg(z)(h)] x.
$$
Similarly, for any function $p:  \Bbb R^2 \to \mathcal Z$, we may compute the total derivative of $p \circ y$
as follows. For any $X \in \Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$, the derivative (a linear map from $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$ to $\mathcal Z$) is given by
$$
D(p \circ y)(X) = Dh(y(X)) \circ Dy(X),
$$
where $Dh(y(X))$ is a linear map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\mathcal Z$ and $Dy(X)$ is a linear map from $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$ to $\Bbb R^2$. More concretely, if $H \in \Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$, then the directional derivative "along" $H$ should be given by
$$
D(p \circ y)(X)(H) = [Dp(y(X)) \circ Dy(X)](H)
= Dp(y(X))(Hx).
$$